# How official is Legends of Runeterra content on D&D Beyond?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-beyond

Recently, I discovered this on D&D Beyond - [Legends of Runeterra: Dark Tides of Bilgewater](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/lrdtob). It appears to have some [new subclasses](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/lrdtob/heroes-and-scoundrels-of-bilgewater) included.

On the one hand, this is on D&D Beyond, but on the other hand, there's no officially released books like this as far as I know.

Is this anything official, or is this essentially just D&D Beyond's homebrew?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Adam Bradford](https://www.dndbeyond.com/members/BadEye), co-founder of D&D Beyond, posted [the following on D&D Beyond's forums](https://www.dndbeyond.com/forums/d-d-beyond-general/news-announcements/71981-legends-of-runeterra-content-available-through) (emphasis mine):

> We recently released 'Legends of Runeterra' **unofficial content** on D&D Beyond, and we are thrilled with the enthusiastic response we have seen from the community. This content will be available on DDB until Monday, August 10th.